# Creating an app with input and saving data

Tags: android, database, button, save, row

I want to create an app for personal use and i'm lost.
It needs to have 9 text inputs and 1 save button.
Saving data to second activity with 9 rows.
1 row for each input text.

Please help.

Comment: Please excuse my English but i ment 9 columns not 9 rows

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you want to get user input in one activity and display this input in another activity. Text input is commonly done using an [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) while [TextViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) are used for showing text. You can put these in your layout XML file and then [find them by their resource id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)). Then you will have to set up a [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) for your save Button where you [get the input](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) from all of your EditTexts. I assume that you want to go your other activity after that so you can collect the CharSequences into an ArrayList. Then you create an Intent for you other activity and [put the ArrayList into your Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.CharSequence%3E)).

You can get the ArrayList again in your other activity via `getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(yourKey)` and [fill your TextViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) with the text from your ArrayList.